# How do you find the mean/average of a bunch of numbers from a txt file?

Tags: python, text, numbers, average, mean

I've been given a text file with several numbers

`900 932 298 918 645 505 922 324 979 360 775 53 12 986 764 400 81 923 233 450 897 166 787 148 376 385 49 62 149 618 568 270 52 295 278 705 942 341 365 74 538 604 958 816 634 566 216 919 475 988 732 835 200 741 587 910 183 204 684 349 373 29 503 63 217 213 656 416 350 386 257 827 820 807 369 634 185 690 255 312 380 449 564 615 966 342 153 425 830 365 347 487 550 788 959 79 129 666 115 27`

and I have to find the mean of this set of numbers. I have been stuck on this question for a few hours and honestly still don't know where to start. Please help a struggling college student who has to wake up at 6am tomorrow out -- I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: How do you find the formula of finding the mean/average?

Comment: What have you tried? What exactly is your problem? Loading these numbers from a file or calculating the average?

Comment: If you only have this one file take your calculator and run the numbers. ;) You can even do it by hand

Answer (score 0):

You can do something very simple to get the mean. Add all the values together, then divide by the number of values.

```
x = """900 932 298 918 645 505 922 324 979 360 775 53 12 986 764 400 81 923 233 450 897 166 787 148 376 385 49 62 149 618 568 270 52 295 278 705 942 341 365 74 538 604 958 816 634 566 216 919 475 988 732 835 200 741 587 910 183 204 684 349 373 29 503 63 217 213 656 416 350 386 257 827 820 807 369 634 185 690 255 312 380 449 564 615 966 342 153 425 830 365 347 487 550 788 959 79 129 666 115 27
"""
num_list = x.split(" ")
total = 0
for i in num_list: total += int(i)
print('Average: ', total/len(num_list))
```

> Average:  487.24

---

From a file you can do the following

```
with open('nums.txt') as f:
    nums = f.read()
nums = x.split(" ")
total = 0
for i in num_list: total += int(i)
print('Average: ', total/len(nums))
```

---

Even easier you can do

```
with open('nums.txt') as f:
    nums = f.read()
sum([int(i) for i in nums.split(" ")])/len(nums.split(" "))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following steps

- read the text file
- split the input text with spaces
- converting list of strings to integer
- calculating the mean/avg.

Code:

```
def mean(numbers):
    return float(sum(numbers)) / max(len(numbers), 1)


f = open('input.txt')  # reading the txt file from the given path
in_lst = [int(i) for i in f.read().split(' ')]  # split and converting to int at same time
print(mean(in_lst))  # calculating the mean..
```